# Ext.Ux.Printer Print Image doesn't work

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs, printing, extjs4

i have downloaded the https://github.com/edspencer/Ext.ux.Printer and
import the Printer.js and Base.js

### in Base.Js i added the image rendder code:

```
 Ext.ux.Printer.imageRenderer = Ext.extend(Ext.ux.Printer.BaseRenderer, {
 generateBody: function(image) {
   return String.format("<div class='image-print'>{0}</div>", image.body.dom.innerHTML);
 }
});
```

Ext.ux.Printer.registerRenderer('image', Ext.ux.Printer.imageRenderer);

### this is the place display the image with id `displayimage`

```
items: [Printtoolbar,{
xtype : 'image',
id : 'displayimage',
style: {
'display': 'block',
'margin': 'auto'
},
width: 320,
height: 240,
}]
```

### When Pressed Print Button Print The Image

```
var PrintImgBtn = Ext.getCmp('btnPrint');
    PrintImgBtn.on('click', function(){
        printImg = Ext.getCmp('displayimage');  
        Ext.ux.Printer.print(printImg);
```

### Unfortunately when i pressed the print button,nothing happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just open a window and print it. In your button handler:

```
...
handler: function() {
    var img = Ext.getCmp('displayimage');
    if(img) {
        var html = img.container.dom.innerHTML;
        var win = window.open();
        win.document.write(html);
        win.print();
        win.close();
    }
}
...
```

Example with print: http://jsfiddle.net/wXfFN/3/

Comment: any better way without pop out window and print the image?

Comment: @C.Y No. It is a javascript. Ext.ux.Printer does the same thing (see function print() in Ext.ux.Printer.BaseRenderer).

Answer (score 0):

if your are using Iframe 'Ext.ux.iFrame', then you can use something like this

```
var iframe = this.down('iframe');
iframe.getFrame().contentWindow.print();
```

if you want to add some additional content along with iframe content

```
 var iframe = this.down('iframe');
 var contentWindow = iframe.getFrame().contentWindow;
 var iFrameNewContent = "<div>This will be helpfull</div>" + contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;

// set iFrameNewContent to content window
contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML = iFrameNewContent;
contentWindow.print();
```

Advantage is that all the styles applied to iframe content, you can see in print document

Also check this link whether it comes usefull
https://druckit.wordpress.com/2014/02/15/ext-js-4-printing-the-contents-of-an-ext-panel/